# pcap_send and pcap_loop interference

Tags: c, winpcap

my problem is as follows :
pcap_loop() grabs all arriving frames from the listening interface and if one of these frames contains IP data i forward it with pcap_sendpacket(). as soon as i send it the pcap_loop() grabs it and processes it again.

somebody may knows the answer to solve that? 
thanks in advance and regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On at least some platforms, sending packets through pcap will, by default, cause those packets to be seen by pcap.  Windows is one of them, so that applies to WinPcap.

The standard libpcap API to turn this off, `pcap_setdirection()`, is not available in current versions of WinPcap.  In order to turn that off, you'll have to use the WinPcap-specific [`pcap_open()`](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcapfunc.html#ga2b64c7b6490090d1d37088794f1f1791) call to open the device on which you're capturing, and will have to supply the [`PCAP_OPENFLAG_NOCAPTURE_LOCAL`](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__remote__open__flags.html#ga337712d5c8d26a0d984d6bb702d0118d) flag in the `pcap_open()` call.

Comment: this applies if reading and sending happens via the same handle i think. can you confirm that?

Comment: ookay, problem fixed. on one side it was the missing parameter but also an other bug i caused myself. thanks!